# My project name is gone, does anyone know why?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, filenames

I'm working on a project as in photo attached (Picture 1) , suddenly, the name is gone (Picture 2).

Does anyone know why?

[image: Photo]

Comment: Cool, I didn't know I can have an app without name!

Comment: Yeah, same here :)

Comment: which os you are using 9.3?

Answer (score 0):

In your info.plist file your Bundle name must be nil[image]

[image]

Comment: I checked it, it's like yours :(

Comment: Remove product name and add any other string

Comment: Ok, I still don't know what to add it to exactly, shall you add the name of which one exactly?

Comment: instead of abc use name you want to use

Comment: Did you try that on device or by resetting the simulator

Comment: I work with iPhone 4, the connection is attached the the laptop, so application goes to iPhone 4

Answer (score 0):

Please check your target name in the project 
[image]

If i am keeping it like this the app name comes blank 
[image]

That change is also shown in the build settings 
[image]

Comment: Same thing, no name yet

Comment: ok , so your app target/product Name in packaging have your project name ?

Comment: It's a new project, after adding the things and ran it, it's good, it's name was ARS and it's written in the project, I have lost  of it's name with nothing as you see in the photo and I don't know when I lost the name

Comment: ok can you please show your build settings Package section it may help

Comment: As you have hidden all the names(in target/product name etc...) I can't able to check in your settings may be because of privacy for the project, the only thing you can do is compare the your build settings with my last image does it have Proper product Name/Module name etc...

Comment: else if you didn't change much just create new project and transfer all the files

Comment: The names where in "the project name" and "my name" I never changed any of them.